# How to pass JavaScript variable to function in Jinja tag

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

```
<script>
       function myFunction() {
                var name = "some_string";
                var display = "{{ python_function(name) }}";
                alert(display);
       }
</script>
```

Above Javascript is writen in jinja2 template. It is supposed to pass javascript variable (i.e. var name) value to python function in macro. I know above code won't solve my purpose as I am not passing javascript variable value correctly to macro. Does anybody have method on passing javascript variable to macro in jinja2 template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass values from javascript to the template that way because the template is going to be rendered before the response goes back to the browser for the javascript engine to evaluate. The only way the template renderer would be able to resolve the value of `name` specified in the javascript code would be to interpret the string embedded in `<script></script>`.

**Update**. Let's look at your second attempt, the one that you say has worked. You have:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="js_fn('{{ py_fn('some_string') }}')">Click me</button>
    <script>
        function js_fn(variable) {
            alert(variable);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Presumably this is in some partial (say *_index.html*). A view that has `py_fn` in scope, loads *_index.html*, evaluates the string "py_fn('some_string')", and replaces `{{ py_fn('some_string') }}` with the result of that evaluation. Let's say `py_fn` is the identity function on strings: it's a unary function that takes a string and immediately returns it. Then, the result of evaluating "py_fn('some_string')" will be the string `'some_string'`, which will be substituted back, obtaining the final, so-called "rendered" template:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="js_fn('some_string')">Click me</button>
    <script>
        function js_fn(variable) {
            alert(variable);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

This string will be part of the response body of the request, so the browser will dump the button on the window, evaluate the js code inside the script block, which will create a global variable `js_fn` on the `window`, which will take something and alert it. The button, when clicked on, will call `js_fn` with the constant `some_string`, always. As you can see, there is no passing of values from JS to Python/Flask.

Comment: Do you mean I can change it like `<script> var some_var = "{{ python_function(<script>name</script>) }}"; </script>` ?

Comment: @Rohanil That won't work either. Let's think about what that will do. The view (or something like that) gets that string, replaces the contents of `python_function(<script>name</script>)` with whatever the return value of `python_function` is for that particular argument. Needless to say, `<script>name</script>` won't resolve to any value in python, so you'll get some kind of an error dumped on the screen saying something like "<script>name</script>" wasn't recognized.

Comment: Yes you are right. It will not work definitely. So it seems not possible to pass js variable to python function through jinja2 macros. Do you have any workaround in given situation?

Comment: @Rohanil I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you tell me what you have in mind, I can try.

Comment: @Rohanil Oh, one thing you can do is this: (1) set up an ajax endpoint on the server side, (2) add a special internal url to the router to call your magic function when something gets posted to it, (3) make an ajax call to that url and alert the response from the ajax call like you did there.

Comment: Thanks, your solution should work. But I am using jinja2 template in flask application. So I have privilege that I can call python function from template without using ajax. I was passing some value from HTML to javascript variable and then I was using that JS variable as python function's argument as shown in above code. But then I made change in my code structure as, 
`<body> 
<button onclick="myFunction('{{ python_function('some_string') }}')">Click me</button> 
<script>
function myFunction(variable) { 
         alert(variable);
}</script></body>`
 and it worked.

Comment: @Rohanil I've augmented my response with an explanation of that will do. Check it out and let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thank you.