# Return javascript variable in Python / Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am working on a small Flask app and I am having trouble finding the way to access a javascript array from Python to be printed as csv.

The general setup of my Flask file is (I am trying to print in the console to see if this is working, then I can write as csv later):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
@app.route('/assemblies', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def assemblies():
    myColours = request.form.get('colours', type=str)
    print myColours
    return render_template('assemblies.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then, in my html I have a dropdown selector:

```html
<select id="Layer1">
    <option value="0">Empty</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Red</option>
    <option value="3">White</option>
    <option value="4">Gray</option>
</select><br>
```

I access the selected value in Javascript like this:

```
function getColours() {
    var c = document.getElementById("Layer1");
    var colour = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
    return colour;
}
```

And in html I use a form to post the results:

```html
<form method="post">
    <button onclick="getColours()" type="submit" value="colour">Click me</button>       
</form>
```

I know the html button is posting but I cannot access the results in Python. I am new to Flask and cannot find the problem in other questions or tutorials. Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: I got something similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390539/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-macros-in-jinja2-template Hope it helps you.

Comment: where is it posting, action is not defined and that is not the way to do that,

Comment: do you want to select many colors or one color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/assemblies')
def assemblies():
    mycolours = request.form.get('colours')
    return render_template('assemblies.html', mycolours=mycolours)

@app.route('/select')
def select():
    return render_template('select.html')
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

select.html

```
<form action="/assemblies" method=['GET', 'POST']>
    <select name="colours">
        <option value="0">Empty</option>
        <option value="1">Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Red</option>
        <option value="3">White</option>
        <option value="4">Gray</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">      
</form>
```

assemblies.html template:

```
<p>{{mycolours}}</p>
```

The output for mycolours is the value you select. For example if you select `empty` it prints `0` and if you select `white` it prints `3`.

Comment: that did the trick, thanks. How do you submit a form with various 'select' on one click? (for example, colours1, colours2, colours3, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your python is right and you need to post to assemblies your code would be like this:

```
<form action="/assemblies" method="post">
    <select name="colours">
    <option value="0">Empty</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Red</option>
    <option value="3">White</option>
    <option value="4">Gray</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Click me</button>       
</form>
```

JS should be avoided where it can be avoided :) and this is not something dynamic, so this will send a post request with colours="0" for example if Empty is selected

Comment: how to submit a form with various 'select'?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post directly as answer due to less reputation, but it should be comment.

Your **select** has no `name` attribute; it'll never be sent as part of the POST. Give it a name attribute as well as a value:

```
<select id="Layer1" name="layer">
```

You can retrieve all values of the list using [MultiDict.getlist()](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist):

```
request.form.getlist('layer')
```