# Trouble with Jquery and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to append an html element using jquery but flask returns an exception:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got
>   'static'

the string appears to be ok, and I have no idea what the problem is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#img_' + element.event_id).append('<img src="' + '{{ url_for(' + "'static', filename=" + element.face_cap + ') }}" width="120" alt="image"');


</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate javascript in jinja? Is element a javascript variable?

Comment: Yes, is a json object value:

Here is all code:

$.ajax({
                url: '/post_browserId',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(res),
                processData: false,
                success: function(response){
                    response.forEach(element => {

Comment: The problem is with parsing the string to html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#img_' + element.event_id).append('<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=element.face_cap ) }}" width="120" alt="image"');
</script>
```

Notice that you can't evaluate Javascript object in jinja2. The `element` object must be a valid python object passed into template.

See [How to pass Javascript variable to macros in jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390539/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-macros-in-jinja2-template)

**Edit**:
To solve your problem you can pass a default img path to the Javascript code and make file urls inside the Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#img_' + element.event_id).append('<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/img' ) }}/' + element.face_cap +' width="120" alt="image"');
</script>
```

Comment: This returns jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'element' is undefined

Comment: That's why I put the notice. Assuming that element is a javascript object, you can't put it inside url_for : `{{ url_for('static', filename=element.face_cap ) }}` this is wrong.

Comment: I've tried:

$('#img_' + element.event_id).append('<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=' + element.face_cap + ') }}" width="120" alt="image"');

but doesn't show the image.

Comment: See the link that I've provided to the answer. Every variable that is passed into url_for must be a python object. url_for is a part of jinja2 template which is a python thing and must be run in the backend. javascript is ran in the frontend so python doesn't know of that object

Comment: Curiosly, the entire code works using javascript object. See:

$('#' + element.event_id).append("<div class='timeline-time'><small>" + element.ts + "</small></div>");

This works fine

Comment: Yes it is a  valid code in javascript. But you put this code inside a jinja2 template in the backend. Backend does not know of current states of the users browser. So it can't evaluate element's value. When this code runs in the backend, jinja2 sees {{ }} and evalute the code inside {{ }} as a python code not a javascript. jinja2 cannot run javascript to evaluate element value

Comment: I was thinking create a python variable inside the javascript is it possible??

Comment: Do you really need to use javascript for this purpose? but, If the path to the img files is similar you can make urls inside javascript.

Comment: Yes, i'm using jquery to automatically update this data

Comment: I would like pass to jinja image path as string

Comment: I assumed that your images are inside static/img folder

Comment: YOU ARE A F... CRACK, IT'S WORKING.. Thanks brother.!

Comment: You're welcome, consider mark the answer as the best answer if it worked for you